# Why do I have to add btn-navbar in menus in Twitter Bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I discovered almost all menus have the `btn-navbar` class. I don't know why I must add this class. I did not notice any effect.

Who can tell me what effect `btn-navbar` has?

Answer (score 3):

This code of `.btn-navbar`

```
<a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
</a>
```

equals this:
[image]

You don't see it unless you are using **responsive bootstrap** and **the screen is < 768 px.**

Check it here: 
http://jsfiddle.net/hajpoj/2bTke/4/

Answer (score 0):

Try searching the [**bootstrap.css**](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/css/bootstrap.css) (18 instances) or the [**navbar.less** file](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/blob/master/less/navbar.less) (4 instances) for "*.btn-navbar*" and you can find all about it.

Mostly layout (**margin**, **padding**, **float**) and some visual stuff like **background** and **box-shadow**.

Comment: Responsive navbar
To implement a collapsing responsive navbar, wrap your navbar content in a containing div, .nav-collapse.collapse, and add the navbar toggle button, .btn-navbar.----at bootstarp . I don't know what mean.How should I use responsive navbar.?